# How to handle error of lightning:recordForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

Right now, I am aware of the `onerror` event of the recordForm tag. However, in the controller, `event.getParam("errors")` doesn't return anything. This is how the controller code looks like:

```
handleRecordFormErrors : function(component, event, helper) {
    var errorsArr  = event.getParam("errors");
    for (var i = 0; i < errorsArr.length; i++) {
        console.log("error " + i + ": " + JSON.stringify(errorsArr[i]));
    }
}
```

In the debug logs, a duplicate detection error gets logged, but the error in the frontend is always this: `An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.`, and `event.getParams()` in the controller gives me nothing. How should I catch this error, or at least change the error message to something user friendly?

Comment: I see that you're used to Markdown, but unfortunately, the `\`\`\`` thing doesn't work; you need to use four spaces instead. In the future, consider using the `{}` button to auto-format your code.

Comment: it looked ok when i posted. alright noted @sfdcfox

Comment: The difference is that the four-spaces generates a proper grey square and is easier to read, especially in large code blocks. It also provides scrolling if it overflows horizontally or is too tall, and has a different effect on mobile devices.

Comment: Can you put your complete code where you are setting the template. The state should not be SUCCESS in case of error. Please show where the server call happening

Comment: Hello @AvijitChakraborty. There is no explicit server call happening because lightning:recordform takes care of that behind the scenes. The loading and the saving of data is all taken cared of by that component.

Answer (score 0):

`lightning:recordForm` is based off of `lightning:recordEditForm`.  If you look at the [recordEditForm documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation), you'll see the structure of the params:

```
EVENT   PARAMETER   TYPE    DESCRIPTION
onerror   error     Object  The error data returned by the form submission.

                            errorCode: An error code with information about the error, 
                                       for example, INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
                            message: Description of error. We recommend using 
                                     lightning:messages as described in the examples to display your error messages in the UI.
```

Try using `event.getParam("message");` to see the error message, or just `console.log(JSON.stringify(event.getParams()));` to see the errorCode as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

*Your.cmp*

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib" /> <!-- this line is really important-->
    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Account" onload="{!c.handleCreateLoad}" onerror="{!c.handleError}">
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="nameField" fieldName="Name"/>
    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

*YourController.js*

```
handleError : function(component, event, helper) {
    var error = event.getParam("error");
    console.log(error);
    component.find("notifLib").showToast({ "variant":"error", "title": "Unexpected Error Here", "message": "A message that you want to show. Can place some error attributes if you need" });
}
```

Please, don't forget this line in your component, is the key to view the message

```
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib" /> <!-- this line is really important-->
```

You can check the [form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation) and [nofitications](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation) documentation

Hope to be helpfull! =)

Answer (score 0):

This has now been raised as a Known Issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmjRQAS

(Found that information here: [Issue with error messages on Lighting:recordform](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222176/issue-with-error-messages-on-lightingrecordform))