# Issue with error messages on Lighting:recordform

Tags: error-messages, lightning-record-form

There seems to be an issue with the error handling on lightning:recordForm, and some real limitations on lightning:recordEditForm. Trying to determine if this is a bug or a mistake on my part.

Example - create this component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsList" type="String[]" default="['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Phone', 'Email']"/>

    <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--large">
        <legend id="accountsearchform"
                class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-p-vertical--medium">New Contact
        </legend>

        <lightning:messages aura:id="emessages" />

        <lightning:recordForm
                aura:id="newcontactform"
                objectApiName="Contact"
                fields="{!v.fieldsList}"
                columns="2"
                mode="edit"
                onerror="{!c.handleError}"
                />

        <lightning:recordEditForm
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"
            objectApiName="Contact">

            <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
            <lightning:messages />

            <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Email" />

            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>


    </fieldset>
    </aura:component>
```

And then add this simple handler:

```
({
    handleError: function(component, event) {
        var errors = event.getParams();
        console.log("response", JSON.stringify(errors));
    }

})
```

Finally, create a dummy validation rule to make the save fail, add the component somewhere and try and save a contact

All I see is this generic alert:
[image]

But more crucially, with the lightning:recordForm, the error handler fires, but the event params response in the handler is totally empty.

With the lightning:recordEditForm, you get the same a generic alert that the save failed, but the response in the handler has the actual error messages at least.

So am I doing something wrong with the new recordForm? Why are there no errors in the response? And with the editform, do I need to write my own handler to expose those messages? Or can I add something else to the form to show the details to the user?

Comment: Running into the same issue.  Have you opened a case with SFDC?

Comment: The Product Manager said he'd take a look at the example, so waiting on his confirmation before raising a bug. But I ended up reverting to recordEditForm so I could keep moving things forward

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I have the same problem with the errors handling...

Comment: raised a case with code sample - will let you know if I get a resolution/Known Issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been raised as a Known Issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmjRQAS

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it's not too late, I see the Known Issue is still "In Review" though.

Instead of the generic error message, I found useful to use either:

```
event.getParam('detail');
```

or

```
event.getParam('ouput')['errors'][0]['message']; // event.getParam('ouput')['errors'] is an array of json objects with the property 'message', at least with one error, it's the same of event.getParam('detail').
```